# CUPS what command do we use to get information about the user?

Tags: printing, users, cups-lpd

I'd like to know if there's a command that let you get information about the user of the printer like how much pages he had printed  ...etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the information from `/var/log/cups/page_log*`, after that, it's a SMOP.